# Custom error template throws fatal error

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I created the file

```
/myapp/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig
```

with this content

```
{% extends 'MyappBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div>
    <h1>Error</h1>
    <p>The server returned a "{{ status_code }} {{ status_text }}".</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is how I extend all templates in my app, and it works without any problem. But it doesn't work for the error handling. I always get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Unable to find entity.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php:218 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\src\myapp\MyappBundle\Controller\AddressController.php(207): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->createNotFoundException('Unable to find ...') #1 [internal function]: myapp\MyappBundle\Controller\AddressController->showAction('=k21RBNjM') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\bootstrap.php.cache(3020): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2982): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\bootstrap.php.cache(3131): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\bootstrap.php.cache(2376) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\bootstrap.php.cache on line 2998

This is how I throw the 404 error:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')->find($id);
if (!$entity) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find entity.');
}
```

I am using Win7 with PHP v5.5.6 and Symfony v2.6.3. When running on my production server, I get a blank page (no sourcecode at all). And –surely– I've cleared my cache.

## Update

When I try to [preview my error page in dev mode](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages), I get this error message:

> The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes; NULL and array given in TwigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig at line 1.

I don't use `twig_array_merge` at all.

## Update 2

This is caused by a `path()` call where I merge the `_route_params` and the `_locale` in my `footer.html.twig` that I include from my `MyappBundle::base.html.twig` file:

```
<a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': lang})) }}"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ lang }}"></span> {{ lang }}</a>
```

It works on all my templates except on the error template. What is wrong here, how can I fix that?

Comment: Mayby in base.html.twig  twig_array_merge throw error ? ...

Comment: No, I don't use twig_array_merge at all.

Comment: @Gregsparrow is on the right track.  I can reproduce the error with `'MyappBundle::base.html.twig'`.  Try moving the base template into your bundle, e.g. `'MyappBundle:Default:base.html.twig'`

Comment: Doesn't apply in my case. If I file `MyappBundle::base.html.twig` to `MyappBundle:Default:base.html.twig` the error remains.

Comment: So, to confirm: error persists after 1) moving base template, 2) modifying error template, and 3) clearing prod cache?

Comment: I can confirm 1 and 3. What you mean by #2?

Comment: If there exists `...\MyBundle\Resources\views\Default\base.html.twig`, then `...\app\Resources\TwigBundle\views\Exception\error.html.twig` should contain `{% extends 'MyappBundle:Default:base.html.twig' %}`

Comment: Yes, I confirm that, too.

Comment: Please post contents of `base.html.twig`.

Comment: Have a look at Update #2, I think the problem is caused by the fact that on error calls, `_param_routes` is null instead of an empty array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution, although not necessarily the most desirable, is to modify the line in Update 2 as follows:

```
{% if app.request.get('_route_params') is not null %}
<a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': lang})) }}"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ lang }}"></span> {{ lang }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That helps, yeah. Although it's just a workaround (it's probably a bug).